# Shortcut between graphical layout and XML

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-adt

I hate using the mouse and I can't find an answer for this anywhere. Does anybody know if there is one. And no I'm not talking about the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> that changes the view and I'm also not talking about the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to change between tabs. I'm talking about the tabs in the bottom, for example for an Android XML layout and the graphical layout, which is the one I guess most people in Android programming use.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

BTW you can change it in `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Keys` -> `Next Sub-Tab` and `Previous Sub-Tab`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good answer: Alt+PageUp/PageDn on Linux/Win.

[Here is help for you](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=13104)